# XPath Perl get attribute value

Tags: perl, xpath, attributes

I'm trying to get XPath to return an attribute value yet first search for the tag's contents, i.e. if I have

```
<select name="xxx">
  <option=bla>123</option>
  <option=blubb>456</option>
</select>
```

I want to say, "search for the option tag containing 456 within a certain select tag with name "xxx".

I do this:

```
my $xp = XML::XPathEngine->new();
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($mech->content);
my $search = $xp->find('//select[@name="xxx"]/option[.=~ /' . $re . '/]/@value', $tree);
```

($re is a regexp for the option part.)

All it returns on the last line ($xp->find) is

```
Can't locate object method "getRootNode" via package "HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath::Attribute" at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/XML/XPathEngine/NodeSet.pm line 90, <MYFILE> line 1.
```

What's wrong here? Is that module faulty? Is my XPath faulty? Should I use something else that "just works"?

PS. I don't use XML::Parser because it complains about a perfectly valid page

```
mismatched tag at line 9, column 3, byte 427 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i586-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>aaaa</title>
<link href="/x/include/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/x/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/x/include/layout.js"></script>
</head>

<body style=
.....
```

Comment: your perfectly valid HTML is not a well formed XML: look that `link` and `meta` elements are not empty. Also a real XPath 1.0 would be `//select[@name='xxx']/option[.='456']`, there is no `=~` comparison operator. And last, your input sample is no even valid HTML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your example HTML doesn't have any value attributes, and you don't give a complete example script.  But the following script works fine for me:

```
use XML::XPathEngine;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $content = <<'';
<select name="xxx">
  <option value=bla>123</option>
  <option value=blubb>456</option>
</select>

my $re = '456';

my $xp = XML::XPathEngine->new();
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($content);
my $search = $xp->find('//select[@name="xxx"]/option[.=~ /' . $re . '/]/@value', $tree);

print "$search\n";
```

At a guess, you've put something in `$re` that doesn't work.

I'm using:

- HTML::TreeBuilder 3.23
- HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath 0.08
- XML::XPathEngine 0.08

The reason XML::Parser doesn't work is that HTML is not XML.

Comment: Yep your example works. I don't know why mine doesn't. Ok the option tags are messed up in my example but my original contains the value attributes.

I have now switched completely to REs for this part since that HTML that I needed to parse didn't validate anyway.

Thanks for your help.